# What is the algorithmic complexity of the getProgramAccounts() call?

Tags: performance, getprogramaccounts, scalability

How does the getProgramAccounts() scale as the number of accounts stored on the chain grows?

Comment: it would be helpful to elaborate this question with more details, such as motivation, examples, unexpected observations, etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `getProgramAccounts` performs a linear scan over all accounts, so it will scale linearly with the number of alive accounts.

However, if you enable the `--account-index program-id`, then solana indexes the accounts by program id using `DashMap` (the index data structure is defined here: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/c4ec031daaa9c6650d37ec351fa680d1c92320be/runtime/src/secondary_index.rs#L103). Since it is a `DashMap` which is a hashmap, performance in that case should be `O(1)` for the lookup. So performance is independent from total number of accounts but of course the complexity is still linear in the number of *returned* accounts since each account needs to be loaded and sent over the network.